# A gre tunnel between Mikrotik and Cisco router

Tags: cisco, mikrotik, tunnel, gre

I really need your help

I'm trying to connect a Mikrotik router with a Cisco router with GRE tunnel using Public IPS

the problem is when I try to configure keep alive between both routers the tunnel is down when there is not keep alive the tunnel is up

I really need your help telling me where to search I'm sure the problem is in Mikrotik

Best Regards

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configurations of both devices.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: In addition to what @RonTrunk said, please note, there is no "standard keep alive" in the GRE protocol. There is a Cisco proprietary "keepalive" extension, but does Mikrotik support it? And vice versa, will Cisco support a thing that Mikrotik calls "gre keepalive"?

Comment: Hello I really need your help